# Grails inline (inplace) plugin unable to resolve dependency

Tags: grails, plugins, dependencies

I've got a plugin called Media which should take care of image resizing and so on.

It has these dependences:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup',
            name: 'tagsoup',
            version: '1.2'
    runtime group: 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder',
            name: 'http-builder',
            version: '0.5.2'
    compile group: 'org.imgscalr',
            name: 'imgscalr-lib',
            version:'4.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tika',
            name:  'tika-core',
            version: '1.3'
}
```

When I run plugin as a standalone application everything works fine.

Than I created an application and added inplace plugin dependency to my BuildConfig.groovy file.

```
// there is grails.project.dependency.resolution closure above
grails.plugin.location.Media = "../../plugins/Media";
```

When I run-app my application I get this error:

```
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
/home/grails/plugins/Media/grails-app/controllers/frod/media/ImageServiceController.groovy: 14: unable to resolve class org.imgscalr.Scalr
@ line 14, column 1.
import org.imgscalr.Scalr
^

/home/grails/plugins/Media/src/groovy/frod/media/download/CachedContentDownloader.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
@ line 3, column 1.
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse
^

/home/grails/plugins/Media/src/groovy/frod/media/download/ContentDownloader.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
@ line 3, column 1.
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse
^

/home/grails/plugins/Media/src/groovy/frod/media/download/ContentDownloader.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
@ line 4, column 1.
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
^

/home/grails/plugins/Media/src/groovy/frod/media/download/ContentDownloader.groovy: 6: unable to resolve class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
@ line 6, column 1.
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
^

/home/grails/plugins/Media/src/groovy/frod/media/download/ContentDownloader.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
@ line 5, column 1.
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
^

/home/grails/plugins/Media/src/groovy/frod/media/download/DownloadedContent.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
@ line 3, column 1.
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity
^

/home/grails/plugins/Media/src/groovy/frod/media/download/IContentDownloader.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
@ line 3, column 1.
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse
^

/home/grails/plugins/Media/src/groovy/frod/media/image/thumbnail/adjustment/crop/CropProcessor.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class org.imgscalr.Scalr
@ line 5, column 1.
import org.imgscalr.Scalr
^

/home/grails/plugins/Media/src/groovy/frod/media/image/thumbnail/adjustment/resize/IResizeAdjustment.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class org.imgscalr.Scalr
@ line 3, column 1.
import org.imgscalr.Scalr
^

/home/grails/plugins/Media/src/groovy/frod/media/image/thumbnail/adjustment/resize/IResizeAdjustment.groovy: 16: unable to resolve class Scalr.Mode
@ line 16, column 5.
public Scalr.Mode getMode();
^

/home/grails/plugins/Media/src/groovy/frod/media/image/thumbnail/adjustment/resize/IResizeAdjustment.groovy: 18: unable to resolve class Scalr.Method
@ line 18, column 5.
public Scalr.Method getMethod();
^
// and many others
```

As you can see it couldn't resolve dependencies (you can see http-builder imgscalr-lib).

I googled much and found I could try to set legacyResolve true. I tried all combinations (plugin, app, plugin + app) with these settings and with the same result - the error above.

Can anyone help me with this?

My grails version is 2.2.3

Thank you very much

Frank

Comment: try with this syntax: compile 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.5.2'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dependencies are resolved by Ivy, but this depends on POM files being available. This isn't the case when you use inline plugins since you're just pointing to the plugin source. You can either be redundant and add the dependencies to the app's BuildConfig, or use the `maven-install` script which packages the plugin and copies it to your local Maven cache.

`maven-install` is a bit less convenient since you have to re-run it every time you make a change in the plugin that you need to have available to the application, but it's closer to the real install process. To use a plugin that's been published locally like this, ensure that `mavenLocal()` is uncommented in BuildConfig.groovy and add a dependency like you would if you had released the plugin, e.g. `compile ':myplugin:0.1'`